# Tkinter Save In Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make the user change if there is any problem and his actions will be saved when pressed save button. I tried some code but it didn't work. What shell do I need to do?

```py
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title('Hatırlatıcı')

def write():
    text = et.get()
    file_one = open('jobs.txt', 'a')
    file_one.write('{}'.format(text))
    file_one.write('\n')
    file_one.close()

def read():
    file_open = open('jobs.txt', 'r')
    if file_open.mode == 'r':
        contents = file_open.read()
    tarea.insert(INSERT, contents)
    file_open.close()

def al():
    write()
    read()

def clear():
    tarea.delete('1.0', END)

def save():
    new = tarea.get('1.0', END)
    contents = new

lb1 = Label(window, text='What Did You Do?', fg='red', font=("Times", 14, "bold"), cursor='tcross', justify='center')
et = Entry(font=("Comic Sans MS", 10, "bold"))
b1 = Button(text='Confirm', command=al)
b2 = Button(text='See Your Progress', command=read)
b3 = Button(text='Clear', command=clear)
b4 = Button(text='Save', command=save)
tarea = Text(width='50')
lb1.pack()
et.pack()
b1.pack()
b2.pack()
b3.pack()
b4.pack()
tarea.pack()
et.place(x='30',y='65')
b1.place(x='220',y='65')
b2.place(x='270',y='110')
b3.place(x='400',y='110')
b4.place(x='200',y='110')
tarea.place(x='45',y='150')
window.mainloop()
```

No error but not working

Answer (score 0):

change the first two lines to:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
```

since you used the code `import tkinter`, you need to write tkinter before each function you use from tkinter, that was the mistake at line 31, you called Label like this:

```py
lb1 = Label(window, text='What Did You Do?', fg='red', font=("Times", 14, "bold"), cursor='tcross', justify='center')
```

, while you should have called it like this :

```py
lb1 = tkinter.Label(window, text='What Did You Do?', fg='red', font=("Times", 14, "bold"), cursor='tcross', justify='center')
```

**Or** 
you could just import everything from tkinter using this code 
`from tkinter import *`
thats what I prefer to do and thats how I changed the first two lines of your code.

so now you don't need to refer to tkinter before its functions and your code would work fine now.

Comment: it still not working I don't think that it is about it

Comment: did you change the first two lines? it is working for me

Comment: this is your program : https://i.ibb.co/BfZQMGw/111.png right?

Comment: yes it works properly but when I try to change the text part manually like write sth then click save and clicking see your progress it shows the older version

Comment: what do you want to see when you click "see your progress" ??

Comment: change the existing progress in the Text part and when click save see the new one